# Placing "Native Advanced Ads" inside popup close

Tags: java, android, admob, native-ads

I try to put advanced ads inside the dialog box when you close the application, but when you open a dialog box does not load the ad for the first time. ... I am worried that I load the ad inside the application 
 without appearing and at closing I put it in the dialog box for fear that the agent considers it a google violation to download the ad without its appearance

Constant code from [android developer](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/native/advanced)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String ADMOB_AD_UNIT_ID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2247696110";
private static final String ADMOB_APP_ID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713";
AdLoader.Builder builder;
UnifiedNativeAdView adView;
private Button refresh;
private CheckBox startVideoAdsMuted;
private TextView videoStatus;
private UnifiedNativeAd nativeAd;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Initialize the Mobile Ads SDK.
    MobileAds.initialize(this, ADMOB_APP_ID);

    refresh = findViewById(R.id.btn_refresh);
    startVideoAdsMuted = findViewById(R.id.cb_start_muted);
    videoStatus = findViewById(R.id.tv_video_status);

    refresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View unusedView) {
            refreshAd();
        }
    });

    refreshAd();
}

/**
 * Populates a {@link UnifiedNativeAdView} object with data from a given
 * {@link UnifiedNativeAd}.
 *
 * @param nativeAd the object containing the ad's assets
 * @param adView          the view to be populated
 */
private void populateUnifiedNativeAdView(UnifiedNativeAd nativeAd, UnifiedNativeAdView adView) {
    // Set the media view. Media content will be automatically populated in the media view once
    // adView.setNativeAd() is called.
    MediaView mediaView = adView.findViewById(R.id.ad_media);
    adView.setMediaView(mediaView);
    // Set other ad assets.
    adView.setHeadlineView(adView.findViewById(R.id.ad_headline));
    adView.setBodyView(adView.findViewById(R.id.ad_body));
    adView.setCallToActionView(adView.findViewById(R.id.ad_call_to_action));
    adView.setIconView(adView.findViewById(R.id.ad_app_icon));
    adView.setPriceView(adView.findViewById(R.id.ad_price));
    adView.setStarRatingView(adView.findViewById(R.id.ad_stars));
    adView.setStoreView(adView.findViewById(R.id.ad_store));
    adView.setAdvertiserView(adView.findViewById(R.id.ad_advertiser));

    // The headline is guaranteed to be in every UnifiedNativeAd.
    ((TextView) adView.getHeadlineView()).setText(nativeAd.getHeadline());

    // These assets aren't guaranteed to be in every UnifiedNativeAd, so it's important to
    // check before trying to display them.
    if (nativeAd.getBody() == null) {
        adView.getBodyView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {
        adView.getBodyView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ((TextView) adView.getBodyView()).setText(nativeAd.getBody());
    }

    if (nativeAd.getCallToAction() == null) {
        adView.getCallToActionView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {
        adView.getCallToActionView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ((Button) adView.getCallToActionView()).setText(nativeAd.getCallToAction());
    }

    if (nativeAd.getIcon() == null) {
        adView.getIconView().setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        ((ImageView) adView.getIconView()).setImageDrawable(
                nativeAd.getIcon().getDrawable());
        adView.getIconView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    if (nativeAd.getPrice() == null) {
        adView.getPriceView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {
        adView.getPriceView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ((TextView) adView.getPriceView()).setText(nativeAd.getPrice());
    }

    if (nativeAd.getStore() == null) {
        adView.getStoreView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {
        adView.getStoreView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ((TextView) adView.getStoreView()).setText(nativeAd.getStore());
    }

    if (nativeAd.getStarRating() == null) {
        adView.getStarRatingView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {
        ((RatingBar) adView.getStarRatingView())
                .setRating(nativeAd.getStarRating().floatValue());
        adView.getStarRatingView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    if (nativeAd.getAdvertiser() == null) {
        adView.getAdvertiserView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {
        ((TextView) adView.getAdvertiserView()).setText(nativeAd.getAdvertiser());
        adView.getAdvertiserView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    // This method tells the Google Mobile Ads SDK that you have finished populating your
    // native ad view with this native ad. The SDK will populate the adView's MediaView
    // with the media content from this native ad.
    adView.setNativeAd(nativeAd);

    // Get the video controller for the ad. One will always be provided, even if the ad doesn't
    // have a video asset.
    VideoController vc = nativeAd.getVideoController();

    // Updates the UI to say whether or not this ad has a video asset.
    if (vc.hasVideoContent()) {
        videoStatus.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(),
                "Video status: Ad contains a %.2f:1 video asset.",
                vc.getAspectRatio()));

        // Create a new VideoLifecycleCallbacks object and pass it to the VideoController. The
        // VideoController will call methods on this object when events occur in the video
        // lifecycle.
        vc.setVideoLifecycleCallbacks(new VideoController.VideoLifecycleCallbacks() {
            @Override
            public void onVideoEnd() {
                // Publishers should allow native ads to complete video playback before
                // refreshing or replacing them with another ad in the same UI location.
                refresh.setEnabled(true);
                videoStatus.setText("Video status: Video playback has ended.");
                super.onVideoEnd();
            }
        });
    } else {
        videoStatus.setText("Video status: Ad does not contain a video asset.");
        refresh.setEnabled(true);
    }
}

/**
 * Creates a request for a new native ad based on the boolean parameters and calls the
 * corresponding "populate" method when one is successfully returned.
 *
 */
private void refreshAd() {
    refresh.setEnabled(false);
    builder = new AdLoader.Builder(this, ADMOB_AD_UNIT_ID);
    builder.forUnifiedNativeAd(new UnifiedNativeAd.OnUnifiedNativeAdLoadedListener() {
        // OnUnifiedNativeAdLoadedListener implementation.
        @Override
        public void onUnifiedNativeAdLoaded(UnifiedNativeAd unifiedNativeAd) {
            // You must call destroy on old ads when you are done with them,
            // otherwise you will have a memory leak.
            if (nativeAd != null) {
                nativeAd.destroy();
            }
            nativeAd = unifiedNativeAd;
            FrameLayout frameLayout =
                    findViewById(R.id.fl_adplaceholder);
             adView = (UnifiedNativeAdView) getLayoutInflater()
                    .inflate(R.layout.ad_unified, null);
            populateUnifiedNativeAdView(unifiedNativeAd, adView);
            frameLayout.removeAllViews();
            frameLayout.addView(adView);
        }

    });
    VideoOptions videoOptions = new VideoOptions.Builder()
            .setStartMuted(startVideoAdsMuted.isChecked())
            .build();

    NativeAdOptions adOptions = new NativeAdOptions.Builder()
            .setVideoOptions(videoOptions)
            .build();
    builder.withNativeAdOptions(adOptions);

    AdLoader adLoader = builder.withAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
            refresh.setEnabled(true);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed to load native ad: "
                    + errorCode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }).build();
    adLoader.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    videoStatus.setText("");
}
```

Now I'm trying to put the code refresh method insaid dialog box instead of refresh method

```
public void showdilog(){
                builder = new AdLoader.Builder(this, ADMOB_AD_UNIT_ID);
    builder.forUnifiedNativeAd(new UnifiedNativeAd.OnUnifiedNativeAdLoadedListener() {
        // OnUnifiedNativeAdLoadedListener implementation.
        @Override
        public void onUnifiedNativeAdLoaded(UnifiedNativeAd unifiedNativeAd) {
            // You must call destroy on old ads when you are done with them,
            // otherwise you will have a memory leak.
            if (nativeAd != null) {
                nativeAd.destroy();
            }
            nativeAd = unifiedNativeAd;
            FrameLayout frameLayout =
                    findViewById(R.id.fl_adplaceholder);
             adView = (UnifiedNativeAdView) getLayoutInflater()
                    .inflate(R.layout.ad_unified, null);
            populateUnifiedNativeAdView(unifiedNativeAd, adView);
            frameLayout.removeAllViews();
            frameLayout.addView(adView);
        }

    });
    VideoOptions videoOptions = new VideoOptions.Builder()
            .setStartMuted(startVideoAdsMuted.isChecked())
            .build();

    NativeAdOptions adOptions = new NativeAdOptions.Builder()
            .setVideoOptions(videoOptions)
            .build();
    builder.withNativeAdOptions(adOptions);

    AdLoader adLoader = builder.withAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
            refresh.setEnabled(true);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed to load native ad: "
                    + errorCode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }).build();
    adLoader.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
              AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                 bulider.setView(adView);
        builder.setMessage(R.string.onfirm_exit)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        finish();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is that you're building and showing your dialog box at the same time. So, at the time you show your dialog box you're also loading your native ad.
You should BUILD your dialog box in advance, and don't call alert.show() in your build function.

So, call your buildDialog() in MainActivity in advance.

In your onBackPressed function call alert.show().

Hope it helps.